# pg_restore ignores search_path variable

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore, search-path

I have database `mydb`, it has two schemas, `public` and `s1`. There is `unaccent` extension installed. It is in schema `s1`.

There is also a function, which calls `unaccent` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION case_accent_insensitive(text)
RETURNS text
AS $func$ SELECT unaccent('unaccent', lower($1)) $func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

I use this function in index:

```
CREATE INDEX project_name_case_accent_insensitive_idx ON s1.project USING btree (s1.case_accent_insensitive((name)::text));
```

Notice, that the calling of `unaccent`
is not qualified by schema. I have `search_path` set to `s1, public`, so
PostgreSQL finds `unaccent` function there and everything works fine.

But I have a problem with `pg_restore`. I create another DB with name `mydb2`, again with schemas `public` and `s1`.
I know the `search_path` setting is not present in the dump so I set it by hand in `mydb2`:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb2 SET search_path TO s1,public;
```

When I try to restore `mydb` to `mydb2` I get errors:

```
$ pg_dump -d mydb -U postgres -Fc -f mydb.dump
$ pg_restore -d mydb2 -U postgres -Fc mydb.dump
...
pg_restore: from TOC entry 6988; 1259 427901 INDEX project_name_case_accent_insensitive_idx postgres
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  function unaccent(unknown, text) does not exist
LINE 1:  SELECT unaccent('unaccent', lower($1)) 
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:   SELECT unaccent('unaccent', lower($1)) 
CONTEXT:  SQL function "case_accent_insensitive" during inlining
Command was: CREATE INDEX project_name_case_accent_insensitive_idx ON s1.project USING btree (s1.case_accent_insensitive((name)::text));
```

It just did not find `unaccent` in `s1` scheme. When I log in to the database and execute
`CREATE INDEX ...` manually, it works fine. Why does pg_restore ignore `search_path`? Thanks.